# how to ping ping a system with host name on a sibling domain

Tags: dns, active-directory

I am having a parent domain A and 3 child domains
1.A, 2.A and 3.A
If there are two systems with the same name, say systemX on domains 1.A and 2.A and
If I ping systemX from a system that belongs to the domain 3.A
Will I get a response?
or
Will I have to use the FQDN?
or
Will I get an error message?

Comment: Hello @PrabanjanRaja, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use FQDN name to ping any server that belongs to different domain because

As Mentioned in this [Document](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/764141-can-t-ping-servers-in-child-domain-dns)

> There could potentially be a **ServerX** in each domain (and it would
> be fine to do so),...so when you ping server there is no way for the
> system to know which domain you are asking about.      Yes, you can
> monkey around with DNS Suffixes, but what is true and valid for one
> domain won't be for the other and so any monkeying around you do with
> it could potentially create other unforeseen problems later.
> Using the complete FQDN when identifying something is the way it is
> supposed to be, and it is the way it should be.